# Format QString with fixed number of digits

Tags: qt, qt5, string-formatting, qstring

When using `sprintf()` when I want to format a number with a fixed number of digits, I have to use format strings like `"%.3f"` or `"%2d"`. Now the Qt-manual says, I have to use `QStrings::arg()`-function instead of `sprintf()`:

```
QString("%1").arg(QString::number(1.3));
```

So how do I specify the number of digits to be shown in resulting string? Thanks :-)

Comment: Its `QString("%1").arg()` but the rest needs to change. Related: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-9](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-9)

Answer (score 1):

## `QString::arg`

You can specify the formatting with `QString::arg` like:

- `%.3f`: `QString("%1").arg(1.3, 0, 'f', 3)`: where the second argument is the field-width (minimum width of the resulting string, `0` here), the third is the format of the number, (in this case `f` means use no scientific notation), and the fourth is the precision (3 number of decimal places).
- `%2d`: `QString("%1").arg(42, 2)`.

Note: When using `QString::arg` you must be careful on using the adequate data type. For example, if you want to format the number `50` with one zero decimal, you must use `QString("%1").arg(50.0, 0, 'f', 1)`. If you use `QString("%1").arg(50, 0, 'f', 1)` instead (note 50 is an integer), code won't compile due to a conflict of arguments.

This is the preferred way to do it in Qt, specially if the formatting string has to be localized. One of the main reasons is that the *placeholders* for values have an index (`%1`, `%2`...), allowing them to be in any order in the string and keeping their semantics (you may need to change order in some languages).. When using `sprintf`-like functions the order of the arguments matters.

## `QString::asprintf`

Nevertheless, and though not recommended in new Qt code, you can use the `sprintf`-like [`QString::asprintf`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#asprintf) (do **not** use [`QString::sprintf`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring-obsolete.html#sprintf) which is deprecated). For example, `QString::asprintf("%.3f", 1.3)`.